# Why does java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occur?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm making an array that outputs a user's input in reverse order. My program works however I keep getting this message, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at Reverse.main(Reverse.java:26)"

I'm looking at line 26 which is, "System.out.println(number[x]);" but I don't see what's the matter with this. Why is this occurring?

```
    for(int x= number.length -1; x<SIZE; x--) 
    System.out.println(number[x]); 
   }
 }
```

Comment: X appears to be decremented infinitely, should it be `x >= 0;x--`

Comment: Come on. Fire up your debugger. Add some printlns. The exception tells you exactly what is wrong and where. Put some effort in before posting a question!

Comment: @John3136 I started learning Java yesterday; so I'm new at coding. I wouldn't be posting if I didn't already attempt to debug and still did not understand. Have a great day salterino.

Comment: x >= 0 should fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop is repeating whilst x is less than SIZE. SIZE is 10 so it keeps going beyond zero and checks for the location -1.

Change the check in the second for loop to be

```
x >= 0
```

Comment: Thank you ! That makes sense, I didn't think about the x<SIZE going beyond zero, I thought it would automatically stop at zero.

Comment: Remember the for loop will repeat whilst the middle expression is satisfied, so if you're counting down you need to check for the minimum value rather than the maximum value.

You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to output the elements in reverse order, but your `for` loop condition is similar to the `y` `for` loop that enters integers into the array.

But counting `x` backwards, the condition `x<SIZE` will always be `true`, even if you run off the beginning of the array.  This explains the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You must stop the `x` `for` loop once `x` has passed `0`.

```
for(int x = number.length - 1; x >= 0; x--)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your for loop -

```
for(int x= number.length -1; x<SIZE; x--) 
    System.out.println(number[x]);
```

After setting x to `number.length-1`  x indefinitely decrements. Once x become negative and the `number[]` array is trying to get value using negative index for example `number[-1]`. Then `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`  exception occurred. Use the following code snippet instead -

```
for(int x= number.length -1; x>=0; x--) 
        System.out.println(number[x]);
```

Your code perfectly showing output because the exception occurred after the output has been displayed. The code displays all element from `number[]` array and then the exception occurred.

Thanks a lot.